# Notification about property's changes are not received by QML

Tags: qt, properties, ocaml, qml

In my test application I use both QML and OCaml which are connected by a C++ layer. There is [sources root](https://github.com/Kakadu/QOcamlBrowser/tree/41430cfe8138d2738523b85faa922d0d307e992d) you can investigate via Github.

Firstly, I want a little bit explain what is my QML [GUI](https://github.com/Kakadu/QOcamlBrowser/blob/41430cfe8138d2738523b85faa922d0d307e992d/qml/QOcamlBrowser/main.qml#L9). My data are list (of length N) of string lists. Using this data I should show N ListViews which will contain elements of appropriate lists. This behavior is simple to the traditional ocamlbrowser based on Tcl/Tk gui.

I know one  shortcoming of my GUI: if data be changed  but total number of *upper* lists won't --- then signal about changing lists' length will not be send. That's why I set new data equal empty list and that I send new real data. So signal should be emitted twice.

[Here and below](https://github.com/Kakadu/QOcamlBrowser/blob/41430cfe8138d2738523b85faa922d0d307e992d/Asdf.h#L18) you can find code describing my property of type int which stores count of lists.

And now we're standing just in front of my problem. When I change data content in OCaml side qDebug() messages before emitting signals are printed but QML content doesn't change: everything seems that signals are emitted but are not received. This is a log from my program (last three lines are from C++ qDebug() side, others are from OCaml side):

```
setSelectedIndexAt 0 to 2
selectedIndexes.length = 1
new path: /2
new_data.length = 1
[ [ Lazy; Parsing; Weak; Pervasives; Buffer; Printf; Toploop; Queue; Graphics; Arg; Num;     CamlinternalLazy; GraphicsX11; MoreLabels; Stream; Dynlink; Oo; Obj; Callback; Format; Complex; Genlex; UnixLabels; Stack; Lexing; Marshal];
[t; create; length; set; get; get_copy; check; fill; blit; S; Make ] ]
selected: [2; -1]
"emitted tablesChanged 0" 
"emitted tablesChanged 2" 
showDescription changed
```

So, do you have any ideas where there is a problem in my implementation?

P.S. I'll be glad to add some additional explainations if you need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple: I didn't call setter from OCaml side. I've not realised that using printing because I used to print same message in setter and notifier.

P.S. Many thanks to capisce!